# R - elegant way to select multiple variables in model like rpart or train

Tags: r, formula

I want to use around 50 variable columns of my data as factors for my model and try to figure out an elegant way instead of using a long list of all variables.

```
rpart(output_variable ~ Variable1 + Variable2 + Variable3 + Variable4, data=Train_Set, method="class")
```

I try

```
rpart(output_variable ~ dataset[,12:50], data=Train_Set, method="class")
```

but that just brings "invalid type (list)

any idea how I can elegantly select multiple variables or save them to reference them in a formula?

Answer (score 2):

Use `reformulate` which creates a formula from a character vector.

```
rpart(reformulate(names(Train_Set)[12:50], output_variable), 
      data=Train_Set, method="class")
```

For example, this is what `reformulate` gives with `mtcars`

```
reformulate(names(mtcars)[3:7], "cyl")
#cyl ~ disp + hp + drat + wt + qsec
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but this brings the following error:

```
variable lengths are different (found for 'CONVENTIONAL_min')
```

CONVENTIONAL_min is the first selected variable. If I use the conventional way with V1 + V2 + V3 it works without this error